# What is this GRPC port-forwarding error trying to tell me about my `grpcurl` call?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, portforwarding

I'm running a GRPC pod in a Kubernetes.  I've started port-forward(ing) against a service with NodePort(s).  And when I run `grpcurl`, every call to the grpc method seems to cause this output from my port-forward. (line continuation '\' added by me for readability)

```
error copying from local connection to remote stream: \
read tcp4 127.0.0.1:50051->127.0.0.1:42822: read: connection reset by peer
```

I do get results and it appears as though the GRPC service is responding fine.  I think the server is setup with a UnaryServerChain and then a StreamServerChain (if that matters).

Is this an issue, or a setup problem?  I think this might be expected since HTTP/2 is supposed to be long lived.

**More information:**

Not in the cloud.  Running locally in a `kind` cluster.  I'm planning to revisit this using minikube to see if that matters.  I'm using v1.20.0 of both kubectl and k8s.  Reproduction steps are touble some to sum up since it involves making protos, pb.go files, start the grpc server, a k8s deployment and a k8s service.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your system - it is in cloud, on premise, kubernetes version, etc.? It would be good, if you can provide info for minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce it.

Comment: Added some additional info above.